# Thread synchronizing with mutex

Tags: c, unix, pthreads, mutex

I have two threads. First one should write:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

Second one should write:

```
am 1
am 2
am 3
am 4
am 5
am 6
am 7
am 8
am 9
```

This is my code:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

pthread_mutex_t mutex;

int firstCounter = 0;
int secondCounter = 0;

void *writeloop(void *arg) {
    while(firstCounter < 10) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        firstCounter++;
        printf("%d\n", firstCounter);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    }
    exit(0);
}

void *readLoop(void *arg) {
    while(secondCounter < 10) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        secondCounter++;
        printf("am %d\n", secondCounter);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    }
    exit(0);
}

int main(void)
{
    pthread_t tid, fid;
    pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL);
    pthread_create(&tid, NULL, writeloop, NULL);
    pthread_create(&fid, NULL, readLoop, NULL);
    pthread_join(tid, NULL);
    pthread_join(fid, NULL);
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex);
    return 0;
}
```

But its not working correctly. Sometimes the second method doesnt work, sometimes it works. Sometimes the first one work correctly, sometimes it prints:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
```

Where is my mistake?

Comment: Because you put `exit` in both your thread functions.

Comment: Where should i put it? To only one of my thread functions?

Comment: If you want both of your threads to complete, then don't put it anywhere (other than at the end of `main`, perhaps).

Comment: Key is that exit ends the process, not the thread.  There is a pthread_exit but you don't actually need it here.

Comment: I delete the exit(0) lines, but now the second function works before the first one finishes his job. I want them work in order

Comment: Stop misusing mutexes.  Use two semaphores and signal a single 'print token' unit between the threads.

Comment: If you want your output to be strictly interlaced, then don't use threads.

Comment: But i have to use mutexes

Comment: a printf() completion does not mean the data is actually output yet.  To assure the data is actually output, insert a flush(stdout); after each printf()

Answer (score 0):

As the commenter suggested, don't call exit() on the thread functions because that's used to terminate a process.

Might also be a good idea to call fflush(stdout) after each printf() as well to
ensure that the print buffer is flushed by the thread that last wrote to it.

Not sure why you're using a global variable in your while() loop. Probably better to use a for loop with a local variable.

Comment: thats not my real code, i will file processes there in the methods. On the first one, i will read a string from keyboard and write it to a file. After that, the second thread should read the file and write its content to the screen. But i cant run the functions in order.

Comment: Then I'm a bit confused here then. If you need to perform two actions *consecutively* then threads are not necessary - you only need threads when you want to perform multiple operations simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

Better to use two different mutex variables to handle the two thread for read and write operation.

Since In current situation it fully depends upon the scheduling, if write thread gets schedule first then it acquire the mutex lock. So, later read thread has to wait for mutex lock until write thread released it and vice-versa.